# Get current Server Time from Firebase Realtime DB in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use this function to get the Servertime Offset from the firebase Server:

```
getCurrentServerTime(){ (date) in

        let serverDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date)
        print(serverDate)
}

public func getCurrentServerTime(completionHandler:@escaping (Double) -> ()){
        Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/serverTimeOffset").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let time = snapshot.value as? Double{
                completionHandler(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 + time)
            }else{
                completionHandler(0)

            }
        }
    }
```

But when i change the device time, the result changes too. Any ideas what i`m doing wrong? It should give me the difference between the device date and the server date.

The resulting server date is always 2 hours behind my device date. It has nothing to do with the server real date.

Comment: What is the value of `time` returned from the server?

Comment: Something around 1529150184.26822 with a device date of 2018-06-16 11:57:29

Comment: I mean what does it represent? Is it the UNIX timestamp of the server? Is the server timezone UTC?

Comment: The docs say epoch time in milliseconds. And they convert the result like i do. The result is working and i get always a date with 2 hours difference to my device date.